# pandas: complex filter on rows of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to filter rows by a function of each row, e.g.

```
def f(row):
  return sin(row['velocity'])/np.prod(['masses']) > 5

df = pandas.DataFrame(...)
filtered = df[apply_to_all_rows(df, f)]
```

Or for another more complex, contrived example,

```
def g(row):
  if row['col1'].method1() == 1:
    val = row['col1'].method2() / row['col1'].method3(row['col3'], row['col4'])
  else:
    val = row['col2'].method5(row['col6'])
  return np.sin(val)

df = pandas.DataFrame(...)
filtered = df[apply_to_all_rows(df, g)]
```

*How can I do so?*

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You can do this using `DataFrame.apply`, which applies a function along a given axis,

```
In [3]: df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
          a         b         c
0 -0.001968 -1.877945 -1.515674
1 -0.540628  0.793913 -0.983315
2 -1.313574  1.946410  0.826350
3  0.015763 -0.267860 -2.228350
4  0.563111  1.195459  0.343168

In [6]: df[df.apply(lambda x: x['b'] > x['c'], axis=1)]
Out[6]: 
          a         b         c
1 -0.540628  0.793913 -0.983315
2 -1.313574  1.946410  0.826350
3  0.015763 -0.267860 -2.228350
4  0.563111  1.195459  0.343168
```

Comment: There is no need for `apply` in this situation. A regular boolean index will work just fine. `df[df['b] > df['c']]`. There are very few situations that actually require `apply` and even few that need it with `axis=1`

Comment: @TedPetrou What if your not sure that every element in your dataframe is of the right type. Does a regular boolean index support exception handling?

Answer (score 14):

Suppose I had a DataFrame as follows:

```
In [39]: df
Out[39]: 
      mass1     mass2  velocity
0  1.461711 -0.404452  0.722502
1 -2.169377  1.131037  0.232047
2  0.009450 -0.868753  0.598470
3  0.602463  0.299249  0.474564
4 -0.675339 -0.816702  0.799289
```

I can use sin and DataFrame.prod to create a boolean mask:

```
In [40]: mask = (np.sin(df.velocity) / df.ix[:, 0:2].prod(axis=1)) > 0

In [41]: mask
Out[41]: 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
```

Then use the mask to select from the DataFrame:

```
In [42]: df[mask]
Out[42]: 
      mass1     mass2  velocity
3  0.602463  0.299249  0.474564
4 -0.675339 -0.816702  0.799289
```

Comment: actually, this was probably a bad example: `np.sin` automatically broadcasts to all elements.  What if I replaced it with a less intelligent function that could only handle one input at a time?

Answer (score 9):

The best approach I've found is, instead of using `reduce=True` to avoid errors for empty df (since this arg is deprecated anyway), just check that df size > 0 before applying the filter:

```
def my_filter(row):
    if row.columnA == something:
        return True

    return False

if len(df.index) > 0:
    df[df.apply(my_filter, axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Specify `reduce=True` to handle empty DataFrames as well.

```
import pandas as pd

t = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'])
t[t.apply(lambda x: x['a'] > 1, axis=1, reduce=True)]
```

https://crosscompute.com/n/jAbsB6OIm6oCCJX9PBIbY5FECFKCClyV/-/apply-custom-filter-on-rows-of-dataframe

Answer (score 5):

I canot comment on [duckworthd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11475486/1849463), but it is not perfectly working. It crashes when the dataframe is empty:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df[df.apply(lambda x: x['b'] > x['c'], axis=1)]
```

Outputs:

```
ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only
```

To me it looks like a bug in pandas, since { } is definitively a valid set of boolean values. For a solution refer to [Roy Hyunjin Han's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46866045/1720199).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `loc` property for slice you dataframe.

According  [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html),
`loc` can have a `callable function` as argument.

```
In [3]: df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [4]: df
Out[4]: 
          a         b         c
0 -0.001968 -1.877945 -1.515674
1 -0.540628  0.793913 -0.983315
2 -1.313574  1.946410  0.826350
3  0.015763 -0.267860 -2.228350
4  0.563111  1.195459  0.343168

# define lambda function
In [5]: myfilter = lambda x: x['b'] > x['c']

# use my lambda in loc
In [6]: df1 = df.loc[myfilter ]
```

if you want to combine your filter function `myfilter`  with other filter criteria

```
df1 = df.loc[myfilter ].loc[(df.b >= 0.5)]
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer, but a typo in the code is probably why it is downvoted. In [6] you should write `df1 = df.loc[myfilter]` instead of `df1 = df.loc[fif]`