# Complex Filtering of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I've just started working with Pandas and I am trying to figure if it is the right tool for my problem.

I have a dataset:

```
date, sourceid, destid, h1..h12
```

I am basically interested in the sum of each of the H1..H12 columns, but, I need to exclude multiple ranges from the dataset.

Examples would be to:

> exclude H4, H5, H6 data where sourceid = 4944 and   exclude H8, H9-H12
>   where destination = 481981 and ...

... this can go on for many many filters as we are 
constantly removing data to get close to our final model.

I think I saw in a solution that I could build a list of the filters I would want and then create a function to test against, but I haven't found a good example to work from.

My initial thought was to create a copy of the df and just remove the data we didn't want and if we need it back - we could just copy it back in from the origin df, but that seems like the wrong road.

Answer (score 5):

By using masks, you don't have to remove data from the dataframe. E.g.:

```
mask1 = df.sourceid == 4944
var1 = df[mask1]['H4','H5','H6'].sum()
```

Or directly do:

```
var1 = df[df.sourceid == 4944]['H4','H5','H6'].sum()
```

In case of multiple filters, you can combine the Boolean masks with Boolean operators:

```
totmask = mask1 & mask2
```

Comment: I think this helps me see how to do my reporting, but I don't know that it helps me with my exclusions.  I should have mentioned I have 600K rows of data we are looking at and we'll probably have upwards of 200 filters to reduce the dataset by.  I've started to look into the answer that was proposed in another question at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418192/pandas-complex-filter-on-rows-of-dataframe?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `DataFrame.ix[]` to set the data to zeros.

Create a dummy DataFrame first:

```
N = 10000    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N, 12), columns=["h%d" % i for i in range(1, 13)], index=["row%d" % i for i in range(1, N+1)])
df["sourceid"] = np.random.randint(0, 50, N)
df["destid"] = np.random.randint(0, 50, N)
```

Then for each of your filter you can call:

```
df.ix[df.sourceid == 10, "h4":"h6"] = 0
```

since you have 600k rows, create a mask array by `df.sourceid == 10` maybe slow. You can create Series objects that map value to the index of the DataFrame:

```
sourceid = pd.Series(df.index.values, index=df["sourceid"].values).sort_index()
destid = pd.Series(df.index.values, index=df["destid"].values).sort_index()
```

and then exclude h4,h5,h6 where sourceid == 10 by:

```
df.ix[sourceid[10], "h4":"h6"] = 0
```

to find row ids where sourceid == 10 and destid == 20:

```
np.intersect1d(sourceid[10].values, destid[20].values, assume_unique=True)
```

to find row ids where 10 <= sourceid <= 12 and 3 <= destid <= 5:

```
np.intersect1d(sourceid.ix[10:12].values, destid.ix[3:5].values, assume_unique=True)
```

sourceid and destid are Series with duplicated index values, when the index values are in order, Pandas use searchsorted to find index. it's O(log N), faster then create mask arrays which is O(N).

Comment: This helped me out with a couple of things.  Thanks for the examples!