# How to filter column values in the pandas dataframe with certain conditions?

Tags: python, pandas

I created a Pandas dataframe and would like to filter for some values. The data frame contains 4 columns namely `currency   port  supplier_id   value` and I would like to have values that would entertain that conditions provided below,

```
* port – expressed as a portcode, a 5-letter string uniquely identifying a port. Portcodes consist of 2-letter country code and 3-letter city code.
* supplier_id - integer, uniquely identifying the provider of the information
* currency - 3-letter string identifying the currency
* value - a floating-point number

df =  df[ (len(df['port']) == 5 & isinstance(df['port'], basestring)) & \
  isinstance(df['supplier_id'], int) & \
  (len(df['currency']) == 3 & isinstance(df['currency'], basestring))\
  isinstance(df['value'], float) ]
```

The snippet of the code should be obvious and trying to implement the conditions mentioned earlier but it doesn't work. The print from the `df` is provided below,

```
     currency   port  supplier_id   value
0         CNY  CNAQG         35.0   820.0
1         CNY  CNAQG         19.0   835.0
2         CNY  CNAQG         49.0   600.0
3         CNY  CNAQG         54.0   775.0
4         CNY  CNAQG        113.0   785.0
5         CNY  CNAQG          5.0   790.0
6         CNY  CNAQG         55.0   770.0
7         CNY  CNAQG         81.0   810.0
8         CNY  CNAQG          2.0   770.0
9         CNY  CNAQG         10.0   825.0


print df[df.supplier_id.isnull()] # prints below 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [currency, port, supplier_id, value]
Index: []



df.info() # prints below     
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 6661 entries, 0 to 6660
Data columns (total 4 columns):
currency       6661 non-null object
port           6661 non-null object
supplier_id    6661 non-null float64
value          6661 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2), object(2)
memory usage: 208.2+ KB
None
```

How to write it properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas: complex filter on rows of DataFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418192/pandas-complex-filter-on-rows-of-dataframe)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use if have mixed values in one column - numeric with strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'port':['aa789',2,3],
                   'supplier_id':[4,'s',6],
                   'currency':['USD',8,9],
                   'value':[1.7,3,5]})

print (df)
  currency   port supplier_id  value
0      USD  aa789           4    1.7
1        8      2           s    3.0
2        9      3           6    5.0

#for python 2 change str to basestring
m1 = (df.port.astype(str).str.len() == 5) & (df.port.apply(lambda x :isinstance(x, str)))
m2 = df.supplier_id.apply(lambda x : isinstance(x, int))
m3=(df.currency.astype(str).str.len() == 3)&(df.currency.apply(lambda x :isinstance(x, str)))
m4 = df.value.apply(lambda x : isinstance(x, float))
mask = m1 & m2 & m3 & m4
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
  currency   port supplier_id  value
0      USD  aa789           4    1.7
```

Comment: And how it works? because there can be problem some values are strings but looks like number. Then it is more complicate.

Comment: I think it is not good idea post multiple questions together. Please post new question with reference to this one. Thank you.

Comment: @Are - thank you. Your sample data looks nice, only in column `supplier_id` is float. Maybe problem some `NaN` values there. Can you check it by `print (df[df.supplier_id.isnull()])` ? If not `NaN`, is possible cast to int by `df.supplier_id = df.supplier_id.astype(int)` ?

Comment: Okay, it doesnt work actually. When I only use the `m4`, I get the result, other than when the `m1, m2 and m3` added with `&`, it all returns `[ ]`. I printed some results from the `df`. What would be the possible issues ? I guess the `supplied_id` doesn't work as it comes as `float` but I will eventually need as `int`. can we check if the `supplier_id and value` are numbers and if so, we would put `int` and the `float` respectively ? Other, then why the `currency and port` doesnt return any things I don't get that.

Comment: Ok, first check comment above and then what is `print df.info()` ?

Comment: Updated the question with info requested.

Comment: I am thinking about your question and without your data it is really complicated. Are data confidental?

Comment: Not at all, just doing some test. You may get it here <https://www.dropbox.com/s/kztzacbfmrc9c1f/sample_data.json?dl=0>. However, the code will need to be protected for the `null` values as well. Because, it may run through some `json` files that would contain `null` entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137457/discussion-between-are-and-jezrael).