# Count the number of observations between two datetimes

Tags: python

I have a dataset on licenses where for each license, I can see the day it is issued and the day it will expire:

**Data**

```
License ID    Issue Date      Expiration Date    
1             2008-04-02      2008-07-10
2             2008-06-03      2008-09-12
3             2008-07-14      2008-10-21
4             2008-08-15      2008-11-12
```

Then I want to count on a specific day, how many licenses are active.

**Output**

```
Day              Number of Active Licenses
2008-04-01       0
2008-04-02       1
2008-04-03       1
...
2008-06-03       2
...
2008-07-11       1
...
2008-07-15       2
```

I already have a list of days for which I want to count the license numbers. It is in the following format:

```
activeDay = [2008-04-01, 2008-04-02, ..., 2008-12-31]
```

I think there might be a loop:

for each `day` in `activeDay`, generate a column for each observation (license ID), such that it equals to `1` if this `day` is in between the `Issue Date` and `Expiration Date`, and it equals to `0` if `day` is outside the interval `[Issue Date, Expiration Date]`. Then we can sum up the numbers in this column and get the count of active licenses.

There might exist an easier way to use the function `.count()` and set day between Issue and Expiration dates as the condition...

However, I am not sure how to implement either of these ideas, and the answers I found online are only to calculate the number of days between two dates... Could anyone help on this? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418192/pandas-complex-filter-on-rows-of-dataframe/31340575) to find required records

```
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame([['1','2008-04-02','2008-07-10']], 
  columns=['license', 'issue', 'expire'])

parse_date = lambda x: return datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')

dt = parse_date('2008-06-01')

date_between = lambda x: parse_date(x['issue']) > dt and parse_date('expire') < dt

df = df[df.apply(date_between)]
```

So you can use a list to store the result:

```
s = []
for ds in active_day:
    dt = parse_date(ds)
    n = df[df.apply(date_between)].license.count()
    s.append((dt, n))

result_df = df.DataFrame(s, columns=['active_day', 'count'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply!! This really saved me. However, I got an error running code `df = df[df.apply(date_between)]`. It says `KeyError: ('issue', 'occurred at index license')` Do you know what might be going wrong?

Comment: I modified the date_between function to specify the dataframe for 'expire': `parse_date(x['expire']) < dt` but this doesn't fix the error...

Comment: @Tian I was using my crafted dataset, notice the column names in my case were `issue` and `expire`. Your dataframe is not using the same column names. For more info have a read about: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: @Tian Fix column names when creating a dataframe `df=pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['col1', 'col2'])` etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the details and the reference! It works perfectly!