# Apply result to dataset after df.iterrows

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv('./test22.csv')
df.head(5)
df = df.replace(np.nan, None)


for index,col in df.iterrows():
# Extract only if date1 happened earlier than date2
load = 'No'
if col['date1'] == None or col['date2'] == None:
    load = 'yes'
elif int(str(col['date1'])[:4]) >= int(str(col['date2'])[:4]) and \
        (len(str(col['date1'])) == 4 or len(str(col['date2'])) == 4):
    load = 'yes'
elif int(str(col['date1'])[:6]) >= int(str(col['date2'])[:6]) and \
        (len(str(col['date1'])) == 6 or len(str(col['date2'])) == 6):
    load = 'yes'
elif int(str(col['date1'])[:8]) >= int(str(col['date2'])[:8]):
    load = 'yes'


df.head(5)
```

After preprocessing using iterrows in dataset, If you look at the above code (attached code), it will not be reflected in the actual dataset. I want to reflect the result in actual dataset. 
How can I apply it to the actual dataset?

Comment: What do you mean by "reflect the result in actual dataset"?

Comment: I want to reflect the result of the logic in the iterrow to the original dataset(csv). # Extract only if date1 happened earlier than date2 <<< like this

Comment: So you want to apply a filter?

Comment: Yesss! sry, I am not good at English so poor at conveying meaning.

Comment: No worries!  Have a look at this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418192/pandas-complex-filter-on-rows-of-dataframe

Comment: Thank you so much! But.. How can I put my logic in that code? That codes look very simple..

Comment: I mean df[df.apply(lambda x: x['b'] > x['c'], axis=1)] this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `for` loop with a function that returns a boolean, then you can use `df.apply` to apply it to all rows, and then filter your dataframe by that value:

```py
def should_load(x):
   if x['date1'] == None or x['date2'] == None:
       return True
   elif int(str(x['date1'])[:4]) >= int(str(x['date2'])[:4]) and \
        (len(str(x['date1'])) == 4 or len(str(x['date2'])) == 4):
       return True
   elif int(str(x['date1'])[:6]) >= int(str(x['date2'])[:6]) and \
        (len(str(x['date1'])) == 6 or len(str(x['date2'])) == 6):
       return True
   elif int(str(x['date1'])[:8]) >= int(str(x['date2'])[:8]):
       return True
   return False

df[df.apply(should_load, axis=1)].head(5)
```

Comment: I think there is a problem with my logic. I don't get the data I want. But Thank you so much Simon!! I apply it after modify my logic!