# Remove all rows within a date range if 3 or more values (days) have missing data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-3.7

I've made a dataframe that has a .isnull column for days that have missing data.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


Arbdata = pd.read_csv('Arborg1.csv', header= 0)

date_index = pd.date_range(start='1951/01/01', periods = Arbdata.shape[0], freq='d')

Arbdata.insert(0, 'TIME', date_index, True)

Arbdata = Arbdata.set_index('TIME')

Arbdata2 = pd.isnull(Arbdata['Meantemp'])

Arbdata3 = pd.merge(Arbdata, Arbdata2, right_index=True, left_index=True)
```

I want to delete each day of the months where there are 3 (or more) missing values or 3 'True' values. The data looks like this...

```
   Index     Temp         Isnull 


1951/01/25   -23           False

1951/01/26   -24           False

1951/01/27   -22           False

1951/01/28   NaN           True

1951/01/29   -21           False

1951/01/30   NaN           True

1951/01/31   NaN           True

1951/02/01   -15           False

1951/02/02   -18           False

1951/02/03   -19           False

1951/02/04   -19           False

1951/02/05   -14           False
```

I thought of using pd.dropna() but this only affects the rows that have missing values, I'm not sure how to drop the associated rows in the same month. I'm new to python and any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using df.apply() with a lambda function.  It doesn't look like your data has a good example of your "three True values", but here's an example that would drop all the NaN values:

```
pd[pd.apply(lambda x: not pandas.isnull(x['Temp']), axis = 1)]
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418192/pandas-complex-filter-on-rows-of-dataframe) for more details.

Comment: In this example, I would like to drop all of the rows in January including rows that have data, since there are three days with NaN values.